# MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) won't go to sleep, nor will it wake up from sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, hibernate

Occasionally, my MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) won't go to sleep when I close it. When I close the lid, the fans keep going and the computer slowly becomes warmer and warmer, louder and louder. Also, when the lid is closed, the little white "sleep light" on the front of the computer ignites solid (does not pulsate, as it normally should do when asleep).

Then, when I open it back up, the screen will not turn on (it remains black), the white "sleep light" turns off (still no pulsating) and the computer becomes completely unresponsive to any kind of keyboard, mouse or trackpad input. It simply won't respond to anything.

When this happens, the only "fix" I've found so far is to hold down the power button until the machine turns off completely, and reboot. At which point it seems to be working fine again for a while. This doesn't happen every time I close it; only occasionally.

It almost seems like sleep mode has been "inverted" in a way. I'm not even sure if this is likely to be software or hardware related issue, but it started happening after having used OS X Mavericks for a while, and has persisted after upgrading to OS X Yosemite.

I saw a couple of other similar questions and answers, but nothing that quite seemed to match the description above, and I haven't been able to find a solution for my problem in the other questions. Has anyone seen something like this before?

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. I believe it is a problem within the logic board, as mine occurred after a slight water spill although I made sure the logic board was free of water. Anyone know where the SMC is on the logic board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that there was some kind of unidentified hardware failure going on. I tried everything (including bringing it in for service) but the issue persisted. The "fix" was to buy a new laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [reset the SMC](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht3964) as well as the [PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222).

Comment: Thanks for this, Alex! I had not heard about any of these options before. This is definitely something I will try out the next time the issue occurs and, if it solves the problem, then I am going to come back and accept this answer.

Comment: Hi, again! I have tried what you mentioned above, but it didn't seem to resolve the issue, so I guess something else is going on. Do you think it would make a difference to change the battery? There's a warning saying that the battery should be changed, because it has reached its cycle limit.

Answer (score 1):

This exact same situation was happening to me and the weird part is that the machine will sleep initially...say 2 blinks of the sleep light, but then will wake back up !!!

Looking at the Activity Monitor is a process called "Android File Transfer". I decided to kill this process and now my Mac is sleeping.

I am going to monitor moving forward, but this appears to be the culprit!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I don't have "Android File Transfer" installed on this machine, but maybe there's something else running that's causing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues with my mid-2010 mac 13" too.. i am guessing its the logic board and perhaps have it cleaned up and put some thermal paste too.. as well as cleanin the fan. A computer technician friend gave me this hint